# How do I display text from an EditText?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

Ok, I'm using the code:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String value = editText.getText().toString();
```

to get text from an EditText, but how do I get it to display with a TextView? Also, how will the code change if the TextView is in a different Activity?

Like this:

[image]

Well, I tried doing this:

```
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String thing = input.getText().toString();

    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String text = display.getText().toString();

    text.setText(thing);
```

But I get an error "The method setText(String) is undefined for the type String" on this line:

```
text.setText(thing);
```

Comment: not a clever idea to update the layout everytime the user changes text... text change can be fired pretty fast when typing but also especially when deleting characters with backspace. better to have a button to update when the user is ready to update the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I get it to display with a TextView?

Here is code which will update **display** (the *TextView* used in your example) with the contents of **input** (the *EditText* used in your example) whenever **enter key** is pressed on the keyboard (I saw you requested this in a comment to another Answer):

```
    // get reference to the TextView
    final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // get reference to EditText and set listener to update TextView
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    input.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                  display.setText(input.getText());
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
        }
    });
```

Code above is inside of a single Activity.

> Also, how will the code change if the TextView is in a different Activity?

If **display** (the *TextView* in your example) is in another Activity, then one quick way to update it is to store the value of **input** (the *EditText* in your example) as a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and have **display** Activity's *onResume* read in the value:

```
// Activity with display
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // get reference to the TextView
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String inputsValue = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0)
                .getString("input", "" /** Default value*/);

        display.setText(inputsValue);
    }
}

// Activity with input
public class InputActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // get reference to EditText and store in SharedPreference
        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        input.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                      getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0).edit()
                          .putString("input", input.getText().toString()).commit();
                      return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You should replace all hardcoded string literals in my code with a code constant

Answer (score 1):

You can e.g. install a text change listener

See e.g. [here for how to add it to the edit text](https://github.com/pilhuhn/MDEdit/blob/master/src/de/bsd/mdedit/StartActivity.java#L75). Instead of rendering you would then do `textField.setText(text);`

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to get the text from the edit view and set the text view:
This is a piece of cake using the predefined getters and setters.

You need to inflate the text view as you have done for EditText, then use the .setText method

If the textview is in a new activity you need to send over the info in the intent for example:

```
startActivity(new Intent(AndroidActivity.this, Activity2.class).putExtra("user", user.getText().toString()));
```

Then in your new acitivty it can be retrieved as

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("user")
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1:

Use `TextView.setText(CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type)` to make your text view display the text you want.

Answer (score 0):

for resolving this particular error use

```
display.setText(thing);
```

currently you are setting the string to another string and also there is no such function available as settext for string.
Also if you want this to happen on the fly(update textview when user is putting in the text) use a text watcher for that.

Comment: Well how can I get it to update when the user presses return/enter?

Answer (score 0):

define an event handler for the edittext, whenever its text changes extract it and do display.setText()

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for create display text in EditText

```
<EditText
    android:text="Your name"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_width="380dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**result**
[EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLXHO.png)